# Структура программы которая должна выполнятся бесконечно

Tags: java

Я хочу написать программу, которая будет выполнятся в фоне и выполнятся долго.
Есть ли какие-нибудь best practice для этого?
Мне пока ничего лучше вот этого не приходит:

```java
static int FIVE_MINUTES_IN_MILLIS = 300 * 1_000;
static long ONE_HOUR_IN_MILLIS = 3_600 * 1_000;
long itterationTime = 0;
while (true) {
    try {
        Thread.sleep(FIVE_MINUTES_IN_MILLIS);
        itterationTime += FIVE_MINUTES_IN_MILLIS;
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {

    }
    //do smth;   
    if (itterationTime == ONE_HOUR_IN_MILLIS) {
        //do smth 2;   
        itterationTime = 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: Может, в сторону таймера смотреть?

Comment: @user419011 не уверен что это подойдет. Программа должна иметь максимально простой запуск, чтобы ее смог запустить обычный юзер. Простенькая юайка через javafx выглядит понятней, чем создавать джобу

Comment: @ОлексійМоренець таймер вроде подходит и выглядит приятнее чем бесконечный цикл, спасибо